# $\exp: \mathfrak{so}(1,n) \rightarrow SO(1,n)$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, general-relativity

I am looking for a reference where it is proven that the exponential map described above is surjective. Here, I am denoting by $\mathfrak{so}(1,n)$ the Lie Algebra of the group $SO(1,n)$.

So we have that
\begin{align}
SO(1,n) & = \Big\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1, n\times 1}:AHA^t=H, \det A = 1\Big\} \\
\mathfrak{so}(1,n) & = \Big\{ B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1, n\times1}: BH + HB^t = 0\Big\}
\end{align}
And also $H = diag(1,-1,-1,...,-1)$
And $\exp$ is the matrix exponential. Now, I know this is true but I'm specifically looking for a book or paper where this is proven.

Comment: Pray tell, what is $H$?

Comment: @RobertLewis given that $SO(1,n)$ likely refers to the special [indefinite orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group#Matrix_definition), I suspect that $H$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
H = \pmatrix{1\\&-1\\&&-1\\&&&\ddots\\&&&&-1}
$$

Comment: @D.Brito you are missing part of the definition of $\mathfrak{so}(1,n)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is right. I will edit the question now

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: Hmm, $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ is the double cover of $SO(3,1)$ but the exponential map is not surjective to $SL(2,\Bbb C)$. If $\overline{X}$ is a missing point in $SL(2,\Bbb C)$, and $X$ a corresponding point of $SO(3,1)$, and the exponential map is surjective to $SO(3,1)$, then there would be a one-parameter subgroup of $SO(3,1)$ hitting $X$ which lifts to a one-parameter subgroup of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ hitting $\hat{X}$, a contradiction. Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Surely it only hits the identity component $SO^+$?

Answer (score 6):

I am not an expert on Lie groups but here is what I recently learned. Let me denote $G = O(n,1)$.

First of all, the image of $\exp$ is at best $G_0$, the identity component of $G$, which is **not** $SO(n,1)$. $G$ has four connected components, distinguished according to whether the corresponding isometries of $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ preserve the orientation of space and time. The identity component is $G_0 = O^{++}(n,1)$ (also denoted $SO^+(n,1)$). It is an index 2 subgroup of $SO(n,1)$.

That being said, it is **true** that **$\exp$ is onto $G_0$**. This is however not an easy result. Its "history" is discussed in the book of Gallier and Quaintance (GQ) *Differential geometry and Lie groups—a computational perspective*. They explain that the result has been proved by Nishikawa (1983), based on results of Burgoyne and Cushman (1977) and Djoković (1980); and independently by Riesz in 1957 (published in 1993). GQ comment that both proofs add up to several dozen pages. They proceed to prove the special cases
$n=3$ and $n=2$, which are easier thanks to the exceptional isomorphisms $O^{++}(3,1) \approx PSL(2, \mathbb{C})$ and $O^{++}(2,1) \approx PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$.

I am writing a book on hyperbolic geometry where I plan to discuss this (you can check out a preliminary version of my book [here](https://brice.loustau.eu/book.html)). It seems to me that the result can also be derived from the classification of isometries (recall that $O^{++}(n,1) \approx \operatorname{Isom}^+(\mathbb{H}^n)$): it should not be too hard to check that any elliptic, parabolic, or hyperbolic isometry belongs to a one-parameter subgroup. Obtaining the classification is not trivial though: it relies on either the Jordan--Chevalley (or the KAN) decomposition of $O(n,1)$, for which there is no simple proof as far as I can tell (meaning avoiding algebraic geometry), or knowing the classification of isometries *à la Gromov*, which is not too hard but requires a lot of background.
If anyone has more insights to share, I'd be delighted to hear them.

Out of interest: Nishikawa also proves that the exponential map is **not** surjective for $G = O_0(p,q)$ as soon as $p, q\geqslant 2$. However it is known since Sibuya (1960) that the square of any element of $O(p,q)$ is in the image of $\exp$.

Comment: The answer is wonderful! This does not show that you are not an expert on Lie Groups :D